# How to configure the microphone to use the output of the speaker phones on vista

Tags: windows-vista, speakers, microphone

i don't have a microphone with me right now. however i want to install a virtual microphone that can use the speakers output as input. i want to test some speech recognition using this.

how to do this in vista.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not what you are looking for, but you could use loopback cable.

[image]

Comment: cool but i want to do it using a software configuration option.